# Want to insert a row in a table, which has a computed column, by taking row or rows from the same table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with 50 columns. It has two rows inserted.  I want to add 3rd row by taking values from that table only.

```
insert into Sample([IDX],[CODE]
      ,[NAME]
      ,[LABEL]
      ,[BILLING_ADDRESS]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL]
      ,[RDBMS_SERVER]
      ,[RDBMS_DB_NAME]
      ,[RDBMS_LOGIN]
      ,[RDBMS_PWD]
      ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH])
values (select [IDX],[CODE]
      ,[NAME]
      ,[LABEL]
      ,[BILLING_ADDRESS]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL]
      ,[RDBMS_SERVER]
      ,[RDBMS_DB_NAME]
      ,[RDBMS_LOGIN]
      ,[RDBMS_PWD]
      ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH] 
     from Sample where IDX = 2
)
```

In the above example i taken only few columns. 
While trying to execute this query it is showing message as follows.

> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must
>   match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Here Label field is Computed value. [Label] = [Code]+[Name]
How to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

insert into Sample([IDX],[CODE] ,[NAME] ,[BILLING_ADDRESS] ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME] ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL] ,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME] ,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL] ,[RDBMS_SERVER] ,[RDBMS_DB_NAME] ,[RDBMS_LOGIN] ,[RDBMS_PWD] ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH]) 
select [IDX],[CODE],[NAME],[BILLING_ADDRESS],[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME] ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL] ,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME] ,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL] ,[RDBMS_SERVER] ,[RDBMS_DB_NAME] ,[RDBMS_LOGIN] ,[RDBMS_PWD] ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH] from Sample where IDX = 2

[Label] will be computed on its own not required to be inserted.

Comment: No it is not working. Here [Label] filed is computed value. Combination of [Code] and [Name]

Comment: @YSSS But the [Label] value must have been already present in table as you have stated in you description.

Comment: Yes.. but it is not working as expected. It is showing as "The column "LABEL" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator."

Comment: @YSSS OK then use: `insert into Sample([IDX],[CODE]
      ,[NAME]
      ,[BILLING_ADDRESS]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL]
      ,[RDBMS_SERVER]
      ,[RDBMS_DB_NAME]
      ,[RDBMS_LOGIN]
      ,[RDBMS_PWD]
      ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH])
select [IDX],[CODE],[NAME],[BILLING_ADDRESS],[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME]
,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL]
,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME]
,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL]
,[RDBMS_SERVER]
,[RDBMS_DB_NAME]
 ,[RDBMS_LOGIN]
 ,[RDBMS_PWD]
      ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH] 
     from Sample where IDX = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `values`

```
insert into Sample([IDX],[CODE]
      ,[NAME]
      ,[LABEL]
      ,[BILLING_ADDRESS]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL]
      ,[RDBMS_SERVER]
      ,[RDBMS_DB_NAME]
      ,[RDBMS_LOGIN]
      ,[RDBMS_PWD]
      ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH])
select [IDX],[CODE]
      ,[NAME]
      ,[LABEL]
      ,[BILLING_ADDRESS]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[PRIMARY_CONTACT_EMAIL]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTACT_NAME]
      ,[SECONDARY_CONTATCT_EMAIL]
      ,[RDBMS_SERVER]
      ,[RDBMS_DB_NAME]
      ,[RDBMS_LOGIN]
      ,[RDBMS_PWD]
      ,[ETL_FOLDER_PATH] 
     from Sample where IDX = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

"Values" should be used if you want to insert one row of static data (not a result of a query).

To insert a number of rows (or a single row) which are the result of the query use syntax:

```
insert into (column, column, ...)
  select column, column
    from xxxx
```